# android <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true despite no merge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a weird thing happening in my app. I get the above error but I haven't used `<merge>` tag anywhere in my code.

Here is the relevant xml file for the error :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alarm_set_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/mediumGray"
            android:text="SET ALARM"
            android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sleep_text_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sleep_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Alarm set to :"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alarm_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/sleep_text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This code is accompanied by a fragment java file. Pasting it below for your reference :

```
public class SleepSetFragment extends Fragment {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "userProfile";
    TextView alarmTime;

    public static SleepSetFragment newInstance()
    {
        SleepSetFragment fragment = new SleepSetFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sleep_set, container, false);
        RelativeLayout alarmSetBlock = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sleep_text_block);
        pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isAlarmSet = pref.getBoolean("isAlarmSet", false);
        alarmTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_time);
        if (isAlarmSet)
        {
            alarmSetBlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String display = pref.getString("alarmTime", "notFound");
            alarmTime.setText(display);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

**--EDIT--**

Here is the stacktrace file : http://www.filedropper.com/stacktrace

Answer (score -1):

The root cause was in this line for me `R.layout.fragment_sleep_set`

May the source be with you!